# Javascript date object not updated when system timezone is changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone, exec

I have this piece of nodejs code, which initially gets the current date and prints the hours and minutes. Then I change the timezone, and then again get the current date and print the hour and minutes.

```
'use strict';

require('shelljs/global');
// Current Timezone Asia/Kolkata
const old_date = new Date();
console.log(`Old date: ${old_date.getHours()}:${old_date.getMinutes()}`);

exec('sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York', (err) => {
  if (err) { console.error(err); return }

  const new_date = new Date();
  console.log(`New date: ${new_date.getHours()}:${new_date.getMinutes()}`);
});
```

The output I receive is

```
Old date: 10:14
New date: 10:14
```

Apparently the javascript date object is not updated if I change the timezone, when the node process is running. Is there any workaround to get javascript to print the correct time?

Comment: perhaps node isn't expecting you to change the timezone while it's in the middle of doing something!

Comment: Use moment.js https://momentjs.com/ working with time/dates in js in an exercise in futility.

Comment: @admcfadn—I'm impressed. Moment.js can tell if the system timezone was changed but isn't reflected in *getTimezoneOffset*? Where is that mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Just throwing it out there because it might help out with other goals moving forward (hence a comment and not an answer). There's probably packages that could help. In fact, this one looks promising: https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-timezone-time

Comment: I'm interested to know the `use case` of this approach. Why should someone change `system timezone` while an application is running?

Comment: @FazalRasel I'm developing a mobile app that runs Javscript. Assuming someone is travelling and the system time is set to automatically update (like most mobile OS's do), then this would be a serious issue.

Comment: Browser Chome has the same problem.